# How do I convert a SQLAlchemy query into a nested dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, sqlalchemy

I have three `SQLalchemy` tables, having a one-to-many relationship between them. I define my tables as follows:

Car -> Image 1:n and
Image -> CarPart 1:n

```
class Car(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'cars'

    car_id = Column(String(36), primary_key=True)
    license_plate = Column(String(12))

    def __init__(self, car_id=None, license_plate=None):
        self.car_id = car_id
        self.license_plate = license_plate


class Image(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'images'

    image_id = Column(String(36), primary_key=True)
    car_id = Column(ForeignKey('cars.car_id'))
    angle = Column(String(12))

    car = relationship('Car', uselist=True)

    def __init__(self, image_id=None, car_id=None, angle=None):
        self.image_id = image_id
        self.car_id = car_id
        self.angle = angle


class CarPart(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'car_parts'

    part_id = Column(String(36), primary_key=True)
    car_id = Column(ForeignKey('cars.car_id'))
    image_id = Column(ForeignKey('images.image_id'))
    part_type = Column(String(20))

    car = relationship('Car', uselist=True)
    image = relationship('Image', uselist=True)

    def __init__(self, part_id=None, car_id=None, image_id=None, part_type=None):
        self.part_id = part_id
        self.car_id = car_id
        self.image_id = image_id
        self.part_type = part_type
```

If I do a query on a specific `car_id` or `license_plate`, using `db.query(Car, Image, CarPart)` I would like to receive all the information belonging to that car, in a nested dictionary, for example

```
{
        'car_id': '001',
        'license_plate': 'AA-000-B'
        'images': [{
                'image_id': '0001',
                'angle': 'front',
                'car_parts': [{
                        'part_id': '00001',
                        'part_type': 'bumper'
                        },
                        {
                        'part_id': '00002',
                        'part_type': 'window'
                        }]
                },
                {
                'image_id': '0002'
                'angle': 'rear'
                'car_parts': [{
                        'part_id': '00003',
                        'part_type': 'door'
                        },
                        {
                        'part_id': '00004',
                        'part_type': 'wheel'
                        }]
                }]
        }
}
```

I was hoping to find some built-in method in SQLAlchemy that could do this, but so far I couldn't find it. Is there any nice, concise method that can do this? Or am I down to transforming the list that `db.query().all()` returns to a dictionary manually?

Comment: use marshmallow for deserializing you data, this link may help you https://marshmallow-sqlalchemy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 0):

By adding a field in the table definition, I was able to obtain a nested structure when executing queries. In my table definition, I now have:

```
class Car(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'cars'

    car_id = Column(String(36), primary_key=True)
    license_plate = Column(String(12))
    car_images = relationship('Image', back_populates=True)

    def __init__(self, car_id=None, license_plate=None):
        self.car_id = car_id
        self.license_plate = license_plate
```

and similar in the other tables. This will give me nested lists, which can easily be converted to a nested dictionary.